# New to gprolog - how can I make this short program reach the correct conclusion?

Tags: prolog, logic

I have the following gprolog program:

```
father(charles, harry). 
daughter(elizabeth, george).
son(william, charles). 
father(X, Y) :- son(Y, X).
father(X, Y) :- daughter(Y, X).
daughter(X, Y) :- \+son(X, Y), father(Y, X).
son(X, Y) :- \+daughter(X, Y), father(Y, X).
```

Given what I have, I tried this query:

```
| ?- son(harry, charles).
```

...and got a `no` (a.k.a., from what I understand, "Prolog can't prove this."). When I ran a trace on it, it didn't seem too helpful:

```
{trace}
| ?- son(harry, charles).
      1    1  Call: son(harry,charles) ? 
      1    1  Fail: son(harry,charles) ?
```

Since `son(harry, charles)` should match up to the last line of my code, I figured the program would simply start by checking the first part: `\+daughter(X, Y)` ("Prolog can't prove that Harry is the daughter of Charles", right?). Indeed:

```
| ?- \+daughter(harry, charles).
      1    1  Call: \+daughter(harry,charles) ? 
      2    2  Call: daughter(harry,charles) ? 
      2    2  Fail: daughter(harry,charles) ? 
      1    1  Exit: \+daughter(harry,charles) ? 

(1 ms) yes
```

So then it would proceed to the second part, right? It would check for `father(Y, X)`, i.e., `father(charles, harry)`, which was given as a fact!

```
| ?- father(charles, harry).
      1    1  Call: father(charles,harry) ? 
      1    1  Exit: father(charles,harry) ? 

(1 ms) yes
```

With both of these true, why doesn't it give a `yes` for `son(harry, charles)`? As an important note, this did compile with discontiguous predicate warnings:

```
compiling /Users/nicolejulian/Dropbox/AI/test.pl for byte code...
/Users/nicolejulian/Dropbox/AI/test.pl:4: warning: discontiguous predicate father/2 - clause ignored
/Users/nicolejulian/Dropbox/AI/test.pl:5: warning: discontiguous predicate father/2 - clause ignored
/Users/nicolejulian/Dropbox/AI/test.pl:6: warning: discontiguous predicate daughter/2 - clause ignored
/Users/nicolejulian/Dropbox/AI/test.pl:7: warning: discontiguous predicate son/2 - clause ignored
/Users/nicolejulian/Dropbox/AI/test.pl compiled, 8 lines read - 617 bytes written, 11 ms

(1 ms) yes
```

A few earlier experiments made it seem like I basically had a choice between warnings and infinite loops, so I went along with this as-is. (for example, grouping all of the left-side labels removes the warnings but then causes the query `| ?- father(elizabeth, george).` to crash).

At any rate, provided that I can't just 'cheat' and add `son(harry, charles)` in as a fact, what am I not understanding about Prolog's execution steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key phrase in the warnings you show is **clause ignored**. So your father/son logic, everything past `father(charles, harry)`, has been ignored. Try making them contiguous:

```
father(charles, harry). 
father(X, Y) :- son(Y, X).
father(X, Y) :- daughter(Y, X).

daughter(elizabeth, george).
daughter(X, Y) :- \+son(X, Y), father(Y, X).

son(william, charles). 
son(X, Y) :- \+daughter(X, Y), father(Y, X).
```

Then you'll get *true* as an answer to your query.

But there's a further issue in the logic if you type `a` after the `true` (asking for all solutions). Rather than ending gracefully, it goes into a loop and overflows the stack. It's due to the circular logic you have between father, son, and daughter. So you might want to think through that part.

To get around the circular logic, consider the example given in [this tutorial](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~dianaz/tutorial8.html). This case uses asserted facts for `person` (giving names, genders, and each parent, and then uses predicates to establish those and other relationships, avoiding the loops by landing on facts rather than looping back around to other predicates infinitely. There are probably other similar approaches, but this is one example.

Comment: I'm under the impression a Prolog with tabling (such as YAP Prolog, Bprolog, etc.) can handle mutually recursive rules like this but I haven't ever tried it myself.

Comment: What does it mean by "ignored?" Other queries that use the facts listed after`father(charles, harry)` do seem to work, so there must be something it's understanding after all... ?

Comment: @nicole Line 2 and line 6 are each clauses of `daughter/2`. The warning is telling you that it is ignoring the clause on line 6 because it isn't next to the clause on line 2. (or vice-versa). So it's ignoring one of those lines and only using the other.

Comment: @nicole you can also tell SWI not to treat that as a problem with a directive. `:- discontiguous daughter/2` will instruct it to expect clauses of `daughter/2` to appear with intervening stuff.

Comment: @DanielLyons, thanks for the note on tabling. Do you think, in this case, that a suitably placed cut (!) would be an appropriate part of the logic, and provide a solution to the infinite recursion?

Comment: @mbratch no actually I agree with what you said at the end of your answer, that a better approach (at least, within the limitations of "normal" Prolog) is to restructure the code so that there isn't circular recursion. In my experience adding cuts usually makes problems worse. :) If `once/1` can be used, the semantics are clearer and I prefer it. As an aside, it is funny that [in the YAP documentation](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/documentation.html#Tabling) the tabling example is this very problem though.

Comment: @nicole, per the warning messages, it ignores precisely those clauses that it says it is ignoring in the cited lines in the code. Others it does not ignore.

Comment: With all of this said, is there really a solution that involves adding NO new outright facts/novel predicates (e.g., gender-related) to the program and avoids infinite loops? I've been going madly in circles on this for quite a while.

Comment: @nicole, well, the gender-related predicates aren't that "novel". ;) The logic has to be grounded in facts somewhere. If you have a father relationship that simply depends upon daughter or son, and daughter and son relationships that depends upon father, that's a loop. Until you break that loop with grounded facts, you'll continue going madly in circles.